# Count before and after in a group after certain character is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For every UserID I want to count number of rows before and after "Completed" DropOffPoint

| Numericreferencenumber | UserID | Entrydatetime | DropOffPoint | Highlevelresult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001030397 | adam | 30/07/2021 13:06 | BACKSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001030403 | adam | 30/07/2021 13:08 | FRONTSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001030408 | adam | 30/07/2021 13:12 | FRONTSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001042505 | bernard | 09/08/2021 08:18 | Completed | Refer |
| 1001034228 | joe | 02/08/2021 21:31 | FRONTSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001033843 | maria | 02/08/2021 15:51 | Completed | Notsupported |
| 1001033848 | maria | 02/08/2021 15:59 | ADDRESSDOCUMENT | Undefined |
| 1001033850 | maria | 02/08/2021 16:02 | FRONTSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001033853 | maria | 02/08/2021 16:04 | FRONTSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001033854 | maria | 02/08/2021 16:04 | Completed | Notsupported |
| 1001033861 | maria | 02/08/2021 16:10 | Completed | Notsupported |
| 1001040207 | max | 07/08/2021 10:25 | FRONTSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001040208 | max | 07/08/2021 10:27 | FRONTSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001040258 | max | 07/08/2021 11:18 | BACKSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001040259 | max | 07/08/2021 11:22 | FRONTSIDE | Undefined |
| 1001040261 | max | 07/08/2021 11:23 | Completed | Passed |

Final result should look something like this:

| UserID | Number of Attempts | Attempts Before Completed | Attempts After Completed | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| adam | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| bernard | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| joe | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| maria | 6 | 0 | 5 | 3 |
| max | 5 | 4 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: In your sample data, neither numericreferencenumber nor entrydatetime are sorted properly.

Comment: "Before" and "after" imply some order. Since a table is unordered you'll need to tell us how to order the rows to your liking.

Comment: @Ullas and HABO you are right, I've corrected tables now. Table 1 is sorted by UserID and Entrydatetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to get the first "Completed" and then conditional aggregation:

```
select userid, count(*) as num_attempts,
       sum(case when Entrydatetime < completed_Entrydatetime then 1 else 0 end) as num_before,
       sum(case when Entrydatetime > completed_Entrydatetime then 1 else 0 end) as num_after
from (select t.*,
             min(case when dropoffpoint = 'Completed' then Entrydatetime end) over (partition by userid) as completed_entrydatetime
      from t
     ) t
group by userid;
```